# drivers not working

Tags: wireless, sound, graphics, bluetooth, lan

after updating my Ubuntu 16.04 all the drivers stop working, even restarting cannot fix this problem. WiFi , Bluetooth , Audio , Graphic , LAN drivers stop working, brightness stuck to its max level and cannot increase or decrease

Comment: Was it a regular update withing 16.04 or a dist-upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reboot the computer and hold the Shift key until the Grub menu appears then scroll down to Advanced Options for Ubuntu.  Then scroll down to an older kernel not using upstart or recovery option.  In terminal do

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic
```

Reboot and things should work